# Subjects of infinitives when infinitives are used as adjectives

Tags: grammar, infinitives

I recently officially learned that an infinitive can have a subject **For + *subject* + to + *verb***.

For example,

> **For them** to browse the Web is entertaining.
>
> **For Smith** to turn down the job was a big surprise.
>
> **For Jones** to return the favor meant a lot to us.

I am wondering whether this can be applied to other structures where an infinitive is used as an adjective. 
Do you think the sentences down below are correct use of subjects of infinitives?

> Harry Potter series contains books **for children** to understand easily. (Children are the ones understanding easily.)
>
> This is a touching film **for me** to watch, because it reminds me of my childhood.(I am the one watching the film.)
>
> Tomorrow is the day **for us** to start working on the project. (We are the ones working on the project.)

Comment: In your first three example, the infinitival clauses are functioning as subject. In your suggested examples others they are infinitival relative clause functioning as modifiers, where they generally (but not always) have a modal meaning comparable to that expressed by "can" or "should", cf."books that children can understand easily". The relativised elements in the first two are direct object, and adjunct of time in the third. (Incidentally, please don't call them adjectives!).

Comment: So, subjects of infinitival relative clauses are also expressed by using the form, "for + subject + to + verb"? In other words, are my examples correct?

Comment: Yes: the subjects of the infinitival clauses in your suggested examples are "children", "me" and "us". Note that the subordinator "for" is only used with _to_-infinitivals that contain a subject.